# How to: scp over Jumphost to host, both on non-default 22 port?

Tags: ssh, scp

My Jumphost uses port 2222 and my final host uses port 20048, so I used

```
scp -P 2222 -J qiulang@192.168.1.16 root@47.101.168.143:20048/usr/local/var/log/frontend/test.log  .
```

I got the error

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 192.168.1.16 port 22
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

The error "Connection reset by 192.168.1.16 port 22" seems to say the first `-P` did not work, so I tested the command to see what error I will get

```
scp -P 2222 -J qiulang@192.168.1.16 root@47.101.168.143/usr/local/var/log/frontend/test.log  .
```

And I get the error.

```
cp: root@47.101.168.143/usr/local/var/log/frontend/test.log: No such file or directory
```

So what is the correct command for this ?

Comment: From `man ssh_config`: "Note also that the configuration for the destination host (either supplied via the command-line or the configuration file) is not generally applied to jump hosts.  ~/.ssh/config should be used if specific configuration is required for jump hosts."

Comment: You can first establish an ssh connection to the jump host with proper SSH port forwarding and the use the forwarded port to do the scp connection.

Comment: @Robert thanks but check my related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705382/how-to-ssh-over-jumphost-to-host-both-on-non-default-22-port , ever since I asked this question I have not found a way to do it :(