# How to: ssh over Jumphost to host, both on non-default 22 port?

Tags: ssh, scp

Both my jump server and the final host run on non-default 22 port.

According to https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host
I tried `ssh -J user1@host1:port1 user2@host2 -p port2` or `ssh -J user1@host1:port1 user2@host2:port2`

I was prompted to input the jump server password, then them both failed with the error

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: port forwarding is disabled
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

So how do I make it work ?

Answer (score 5):

The man page says the format for the `-J` option is `-J [user@]host[:port]`, so `-J user1@host1:port1` looks right:

> `-J [user@]host[:port]`
> Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple
> jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.

But based on that error, your problem doesn't appear to be the port specification, but the fact that the intermediate host doesn't allow port forwarding, and `-J` requires that.

If changing that is not possible, but you do trust the jump host, you could make one connection to the jump host and run another SSH client there to open the connection to the final target host:

```
ssh user1@host1:port1 'ssh user2@host2:port2'
```

(or maybe with `ssh -t`)

Comment: Or fallback to the old-school `ProxyCommand` option instead (either using `ssh -W`, or `ssh ... nc`)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I spend quite some time to figure out the [jumpserver](https://github.com/jumpserver/jumpserver/blob/master/README_EN.md) we use do not support port forwarding and according [this github issue](https://github.com/jumpserver/jumpserver/issues/130) they don't have plan to implement that either. So I will try "ssh user1@host1:port1 'ssh user2@host2:port2'" tomorrow.

Comment: I tried "ssh user1@host1:port1 'ssh user2@host2:port2'" then I got another error "No PTY requested" but according to [this github issue](https://github.com/jumpserver/jumpserver/issues/4775) they don't support it either. So it seems that they don't support ssh to host server directly.